# I am getting 0 % coverage 0 SLOC in mocha code coverage using blanket

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, chai, blanket.js

I am trying to get the code coverage in MOCHA JS test. I am using the blanket and the but I am getting 0 % coverage 0 SLOC why I am not understanding.
my package.json is

```
{
  "name": "basics",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha && mocha test --require blanket --reporter html-cov > coverage.html"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "chai": "~2.2.0",
    "mocha": "~2.2.4",
    "blanket": "~1.1.6",

  },
  "config": {
    "blanket": {
      "pattern": ["index.js"],
      "data-cover-never": "node_modules"
    }
  }
}
```

and index.js is

```
exports.sanitize = function(word){


    return word.toLowerCase().replace(/-/g, ' ');
}

exports.testToString = function(){


    return word.toLowerCase().replace(/-/g, ' ');
}
```

and indexSpec.js which is under test folder is

```
var chai = require('chai');
var expect = require('chai').expect;
var word = require('../index.js');

describe ('sanitize', function(){
    it('String matching ', function(){

        var inputWord = 'hello WORLD';
        var outputWord = word.sanitize(inputWord);
        expect(outputWord).to.equal('hello world');
        expect(outputWord).to.not.equal('HELLO WORLD');
        expect(outputWord).to.be.a('string');
        expect(outputWord).not.to.be.a('number');

    });

    it('Checke hyphen ', function(){
        var inputWord = 'hello-WORLD';
        var outputWord = word.sanitize(inputWord);
        expect(outputWord).to.equal('hello world');
    });
} )
```

Comment: I am having the exact same issue, did you ever fix this? My package.json script and config looks identical to yours.

Comment: I'm also having this exact problem.

Comment: This issue got fixed when I installed the latest node js

Answer (score 2):

Paul is right. There is no point in using buggy library. Steps for making this code work with Istanbul:

1. Install Istanbul globally `npm install -g istanbul`
2. Change script section in package.json

```
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha",
    "coverage": "istanbul cover node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha -- -R spec"
  },
```

3. Run test by typing `npm test`
4. Generage coverage report: `npm run coverage`

Coverage report will be available in `coverage/lcov-report/index.html`

Answer (score 0):

Get blanket from the git repo. I don't know what's wrong with their npm package, but it didn't work for me either.

Getting the module from git repo works fine.

Make the below changes in your `package.json` file

```
"devDependencies": {
    "chai": "~2.2.0",
    "mocha": "~2.2.4",
    "blanket": "git://github.com/alex-seville/blanket.git"
},
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and added a blanket.js file in my root directory as recommended by Neilskrijger here ... https://github.com/alex-seville/blanket/issues/361  .
I then set my blanket pattern in my package.json to '/lib' which was the root of my source code and it worked. The forward slash was required.  My test script was "mocha --require blanket -R html-cov --recursive> coverage.html".

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a lot of us have used the same tutorial and met the same problem.

I have tried all hints given on this page (tried with node versions: node-v4.3.1 and node-v5.7.0) + a few more without any luck
I ended up with another package **Istanbul**, which I should have done from the start since I normally use the stats as a indicator of which package to use (Its used by so many more users).
First try with this package and it worked :-)
I added this to the script section of package.json:

"coverage" : "./node_modules/.bin/istanbul cover ./node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha -- -R spec"